# Ethereum is not transferred on Ropsten network

Tags: web3js, ether, ethereumjs, ropsten, infura

Here's my code for signing nd sending a transaction on Ropsten testnet which is working properly. However, the value that is set to '1' eth is not transferred to the target address.

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction

const Web3 = require ('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('MY URL including the key')
 
//Public keys for two accounts
const account1 = '0x8dAd70D461d01C2945A0a1b358eDF21544E03d07'
const account2 = '0x2bA9D4119A2F5c80812d273F3720347dd529FD0A'

const prKey1 = Buffer.from(process.env.PR_KEY1.substring(2,66), 'hex')
const prKey2 = Buffer.from(process.env.PR_KEY2.substring(2,66), 'hex')



// *********************Transfer from account 1 to account 2 *******************
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
// Build the transaction
    const txObject = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    to: account2,
    Value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')), 
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000), 
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('100' , 'gwei')) 
    
    }


// Sign the transaction - choose ropsten as the network
    const tx = new Tx(txObject, {chain: 'ropsten'})
    tx.sign(prKey1)
    
    const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

// Broadcast the transaction 
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
        console.log('txHash:', txHash)
  })
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change parameter `Value` in object `txObject` to `value` ( without capital letter ). Silly mistake, but happens a lot :)

Comment: Such embarrassment. It completely exposed me as a beginner :))
Thanks for your help dude